# Is there any difference between specifying a json's key with and without quotes?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there any difference between the following `title` keys?

```
jsonObj = {
  title: "hello"
}
```

and

```
jsonObj = {
 "title": "world"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid javascript objects, but only second one is a valid JSON object.
Preferably use the second one, that also helps when property name is a keyword, or has special characters in it .e.g ":" or space.

```
jsonObj = {
  "my second key::second range":99
}
```

Comment: On the flipside, avoiding special characters in keys (valid identifiers) allows for dot-notation.

Answer (score 3):

As a *Javascript object literal* (as Javascript code), they're identical.
As the JSON data format, only *with* quotes is valid JSON.

JSON is a strict subset of Javascript syntax, they're not the same thing.